# No se actualiza en valor de un JFormattedTextField, al hacer campo.setText()

Tags: java, java-swing

Estoy haciendo un `campo.setText()`, al oprimir un botón este valor se muestra en la interfaz cuando se actualiza.

El problema es que al hacer `campo.getText()`, obtiene el valor anterior que fue ingresado mediante el teclado, no el valor que se ingreso con el  `.setText()`.

Para que este valor se actualice me toca hacer clic sobre el campo de texto, una vez lo hago ya se puede obtener el valor actual.

¿Como hago para que se pueda obtener el nuevo valor con `getText()`?

Comment: Andrés sería interesante que nos mostraras el código que tienes. Para ver posibles fallos o intentar ayudarte con el problema que nos indicas. De todas formas para futuras preguntas te recomiendo visitar [ask] para que la pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad de [es.so]

Comment: Si pusieras el fragmento de código donde controlas los eventos te podriamos ayudar fácilmente, no dudes en ponerlo cuanto antes.

Comment: campo.setValue() para asignar un valor
campo.getValue() para obtener el valor